# How to open and print the contents of a file line by line using subprocess?

Tags: python, file, parsing, subprocess

I am trying to write a python script which SSHes into a specific address and dumps a text file. I am currently having some issues. Right now, I am doing this:

```
temp = "cat file.txt"
need = subprocess.Popen("ssh {host} {cmd}".format(host='155.0.1.1', cmd=temp),shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
print(need)
```

This is the naive approach where I am basically opening the file, saving its output to a variable and printing it. However, this really messes up the format when I print "need". Is there any way to simply use subprocess and read the file line by line? I have to be SSHed into the address in order to dump the file otherwise the file will not be detected, that is why I am not simply doing

```
            f = open(temp, "r")
            file_contents = f.read()
            print (file_contents)
            f.close()
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: In what way is the format "messed up" when you print `need`?

Comment: For some reason, the lines are not being separated.

Comment: That's odd. Perhaps the remote host is using some obscure line ending protocol. It might be worthwhile changing `print(need)` to `print(repr(need))` so that you can see what's being sent.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the subprocess module to print the entire file line by line. You can use pure python.

```py
f = open(temp, "r")
file_contents = f.read()
f.close()

# turn the file contents into a list
file_lines = file_contents.split("\n")

# print all the items in the list
for file_line in file_lines:
    print(file_line)
```